# Solar not producing 24V all the time

Tags: solar-cell, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

We live in a moderately sunny place. We do get some cloudy days frequently. I have seen the output to go above 24V(like25V) on a fully sunny day middle of the day which means lots of days the solar output might not be enough to charge the 24Volt battery pack.
My solar panel setup has (2  * 12V 100W in series  and 2 * 24V 100W in parallel). And both connected in parallel) to produce that output(400W). Is there a solution to generate more consistently 24V in a moderately sunny place?
The issue I have is that with 22-24V output lots of the the days, it is not good enough to drive charge into my battery pack/inverter(minimum requires 24V). What will the right solution for making sure that I can generate more than 24V even on cloudy days?

Comment: any solar system comes (should come) with a output controller whose whole job is converting what the cells provide to a useful voltage. You should have one of these!

Comment: One of the tags selected by you is solar charge controller.  Seems like you alraedy know the answer.

Comment: Where are the PV specs for Voc, Isc?

Comment: V_MPT ranges from 83% to 72% of Voc

Comment: Manoj Ramakrishnan - Welcome :-) This question is effectively a continuation / variation of your [existing question from yesterday](/q/563039). You can't have two such similar questions open at the same time, due to the duplication of effort from readers - some will see one question, some will see the the other, but (until we notice the similarity) no-one sees the whole story. Therefore *this* question is now closed as a duplicate of *that* one. I recommend you improve *that* question (edit it to add any new information). Add more details there (and a clear diagram) of your configuration.

Comment: All right. Thanks @SamGibson will do.